# PHP timezone issue

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the countdown here http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html and I have added the server time and everything but now with daylight savings my application adds an extra hour to all countdown times at http://www.artfido.com

I have tried changing the server time to not update with daylight savings but my countdown still has an hour added.

UTC time is +10 but don't know how to change to not have the additional hour.

Code sample

```
server-time.php  
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1 
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past 
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); // MIME type 
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n";
?>

Countdown script
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
until: endAuction,
serverSync: serverTime,
timezone: +10,
format: 'DHMS',...

function serverTime() { 
var time = null; 
$.ajax({url: 'server-time.php?random=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000), 
 async: false, dataType: 'text', 
 success: function(text) { 
 time = new Date(text); 
}, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
time = new Date(); 
}}); 
return time; 
}
```

Comment: Just rebooted apache to see if that help but nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used code this way:

```
function serverTime() {
    var time = null;
    $.ajax({url: 'cgi/server-time.php?random=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
        async: false, dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
            time = new Date(text);
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) {
            time = new Date();
    }});
    return time;
}
```

This function, doesn't return anything because the AJAX Call is asynchronous. One good way, is to do it in the success function. I meant the initialization of the timer.

Because, when you call this `serverTime()` function, it always returns `null`. It is not instant. Do one thing. Have a function called, `startTimer(time)` and pass the server's time in the `time` variable to the `startTimer()` and inside the function, define this way:

```
function startTimer(time)
{
    var endAuction = "";
    $(function () {
        endAuction = new Date(
            2012,
            10,
            08,
            12,
            24,
            26                                                                );
        $('#defaultCountdown8077').countdown('destroy')
        $('#defaultCountdown8077').countdown({
            until: endAuction,
            serverSync: time,
            timezone: +10,
            format: 'DHMS',
            expiryUrl: 'http://www.artfido.com'
        });
    });
}
```

Also the `serverTime();` you are calling somewhere in the middle, and in no way, it would be useful.

#### Your JavaScript code would be:

```
function initTimer() {
    var time = null;
    $.ajax({url: 'cgi/server-time.php?random=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
        async: false, dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
            time = new Date(text);
            startTimer(time);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. I will work thought my past questions and accept now.

Comment: @KerePuki I have removed my comment. PLease see my updated answer now. The JavaScript is the issue. Not your PHP file. :)

Comment: Sorry I will need to try it a bit later. I have had to quickly update the timezone to +11 for the mean time but I will give it a go a bit later. What format should I pass the time as?

Comment: Time should be a JavaScript `Date()` object as you did in your previous AJAX Request. :)

Comment: OK thanks and thanks for the quick response. Being an auction site the client was a bit stressed and we hadn't considered daylight savings changes.

Comment: Do one thing. Have two copies. Let one be for test. And put this code and check in the testing server before putting it into the production. How didn't you think of having a test before doing some sensitive web application?

Comment: Well we did do a lot of testing but didn't think about daylight savings and now, I didn't realise that daylight savings would add an additional hour to the output considering its reading the time directly from the server.